# How to get a Workday worker / employee web profile URL?

Tags: workday-api

I wish to retrieve a Workday worker (aka employee) web profile URL via the Workday API. The use case is that I'm building a chatbot to retrieve user information and I want to be able to deep link to the worker (employee) web profile.

The issue is that I cannot do either of the following:

1. get a web profile URL from the API
2. create a web profile URL from data in the API

A web profile URL looks like the following. The userId looks like `1234` right before the `.htmld` extension as that is the only number that changes between employee profiles.

```
https://www.myworkday.com/{myCompany}/d/inst/1$715/247${1234}.htmld
```

A search URL in the webUI returns a slightly different URL but has the same numerical userId at the end, e.g. the `1234` before `.htmld` here:

```
https://www.myworkday.com/{myCompany}/d/inst/autocompletesearch/247${1234}.htmld
```

A worker API call is like the following with a 32 byte hexadecimal `workerId` like `deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef`. Searching for the API `workerId` in the web UI returns no results.

```
https://services1.myworkday.com/ccx/api/api/v1/{myCompany}/workers/{workerId}
```

The API result does not have the web profile `userId`, e.g. 1234, any where in it, or a URL that can render a web page.

```json
{
  "id":"deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef",
  "descriptor":"Joe Cool",
  "href":"https://services1.myworkday.com/ccx/api/api/v1/{myCompany}/workers/deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef",
  "supervisoryOrganizationsManaged":"https://services1.myworkday.com/ccx/api/api/v1/{myCompany}/workers/deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef/supervisoryOrganizationsManaged",
  "yearsOfService":"1",
  "primaryWorkEmail":"joe.cool@example.com",
  "isManager":false,
  "location":{
    "descriptor":"Santa Rosa, California",
    "id":"deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"
  },
  "primarySupervisoryOrganization":{
    "descriptor":"Peanuts (Charles 'Sparky' Schulz)",
    "id":"deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef",
    "href":"https://services1.myworkday.com/ccx/api/api/v1/{myCompany}/supervisoryOrganizations/deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"
  },
  "businessTitle":"beagle"
}
```

Can anyone help provide info on how to get a web profile URL from the Workday API?

Comment: One question, how did u add pagination in this? or was it not required in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The ID returned from workday's API is actually the **Workday ID**, not **Worker ID**. The **Workday ID** or **WID** is a direct reference to any object in Workday. This is often referred to as an "Integration ID". Workday doesn't document this very well, but workday's URLs do have an interesting thing you can take advantage of for deep linking to any Workday Object:

```
https://www.myworkday.com/{myCompany}/d/inst/{sourceReferenceWID}/{WID}.htmld
```

As long as you have the Workday ID (WID) of an object, you can deeplink directly. The sourceReferenceWID is just for logging purposes, so you can enter any text you want. I tested this in my own tenant with the text "deeplink" replacing {sourceReferenceWID} just for fun. For your example, the following URL should work for Joe Cool:

```
https://www.myworkday.com/{myCompany}/d/inst/deeplink/deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef.htmld
```

This is not officially documented, so Workday may change how this works and your mileage may vary.

Comment: Useful! How does pagination work in the url you have just mentioned? I am trying to add page number to it to see if there are more pages.. Any idea?

Comment: @RuchikaChaudhari I am not aware of pagination for direct WIDs in Workday, so I don't believe that would be necessary or exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a delivered REST API, but you could create a RaaS with the Business Object "Worker from Prompt". There is a field called "Worker Instance URL". When you call the endpoint, you can use the WID (Workday ID), the Employee_ID, or Contingent_Worker_ID for the filter.

[https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/{tenant}/{report](https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/%7Btenant%7D/%7Breport) owner}/{report name}?Worker!WID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
or
[https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/{tenant}/{report](https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/%7Btenant%7D/%7Breport) owner}/{report name}?Worker!Employee_ID=x